# How to find the standard deviation of a ratio?

Tags: standard-deviation, independence, ratio

I have means from two dependent datasets (leg length [A] and arm length [B]). I do not have raw values for these datasets, but do have N, median, 10th/90th percentiles, and standard deviation.

I would like to calculate the standard deviation of the ratio (B*100/A).

Would someone be able to explain to me if this is possible and if so, a dumbed down way of accomplishing this? I am not very statistically minded, but understand the basics. Any help on this matter would be very very appreciated.

Comment: We can safely assume A and B are correlated. Since you don't know their correlation/covariance, no there's not a single thing you can do.

Comment: Thank you for your response! Hypothetically, if I did have the raw data, would I then be able to accomplish my goal?